# Drupal 6 на php 5.4

Tags: drupal

Всем привет, перестал работать поиск на drupal. Пытался переидексацию делать. Не работает. На php 5.3 работал. Как можно исправить? Права, все есть для поиска. Просто когда вводишь что-то в поиск он выдает ошибку: минимум 3 символа должно быть введено. Хотя введено больше. И выдает пустые результаты.

Comment: Изменения и несовместимости 5.3 -> 5.4 http://php.net/manual/ru/migration54.php В лог ошибок сервера смотрите.

Comment: В ошибках сервера в том то и дело, что ничего. Пусто. Все на сайте работает, кроме поиска

Comment: может просто отключен вывод и запись ошибок? бывают такие уникумы которие отключают запись ошибок  в логи

Comment: еще как вариант просто поищете по всему проекту где именно это сообщение выводиться и будет больше понятно что и как. Еще может быть случай с @ то есть заглушкой ошибок